# Speed up random matrix computation

Tags: python, performance, math, numpy, scipy

I am creating random Toeplitz matrices to estimate the probability that they are invertible. My current code is

```
import random
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
import numpy as np
for n in xrange(1,25):
    rankzero = 0
    for repeats in xrange(50000):
        column = [random.choice([0,1]) for x in xrange(n)]
        row = [column[0]]+[random.choice([0,1]) for x in xrange(n-1)]
        matrix = toeplitz(column, row)
        if  (np.linalg.matrix_rank(matrix) < n):
            rankzero += 1
    print n, (rankzero*1.0)/50000
```

Can this be sped up?

I would like to increase the value 50000 to get more accuracy but it is too slow to do so currently.

Profiling using only `for n in xrange(10,14)` shows

```
  400000    9.482    0.000    9.482    0.000 {numpy.linalg.lapack_lite.dgesdd}
  4400000    7.591    0.000   11.089    0.000 random.py:272(choice)
   200000    6.836    0.000   10.903    0.000 index_tricks.py:144(__getitem__)
        1    5.473    5.473   62.668   62.668 toeplitz.py:3(<module>)
   800065    4.333    0.000    4.333    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
   200000    3.513    0.000   19.949    0.000 special_matrices.py:128(toeplitz)
   200000    3.484    0.000   20.250    0.000 linalg.py:1194(svd)
6401273/6401237    2.421    0.000    2.421    0.000 {len}
   200000    2.252    0.000   26.047    0.000 linalg.py:1417(matrix_rank)
  4400000    1.863    0.000    1.863    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
  2201015    1.240    0.000    1.240    0.000 {isinstance}
[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to save some work from repeated calling of toeplitz() function by caching the indexes where the values are being put. The following code is ~ 30% faster than the original code. The rest of the performance is in the rank calculation... 
And I don't know whether there exists a faster rank calculation for toeplitz matrices with 0s and 1s.

(update) The code is actually ~ 4 times faster if you replace matrix_rank by scipy.linalg.det() == 0 (determinant is faster then rank calculation for small matrices)

```
import random
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz, det
import numpy as np,numpy.random

class si:
    #cache of info for toeplitz matrix construction
    indx = None
    l = None

def xtoeplitz(c,r):
    vals = np.concatenate((r[-1:0:-1], c))
    if si.indx is None or si.l != len(c):
        a, b = np.ogrid[0:len(c), len(r) - 1:-1:-1]
        si.indx = a + b
        si.l = len(c)
    # `indx` is a 2D array of indices into the 1D array `vals`, arranged so
    # that `vals[indx]` is the Toeplitz matrix.
    return vals[si.indx]

def doit():
    for n in xrange(1,25):
        rankzero = 0
        si.indx=None

        for repeats in xrange(5000):

            column = np.random.randint(0,2,n)
            #column=[random.choice([0,1]) for x in xrange(n)] # original code

            row = np.r_[column[0], np.random.randint(0,2,n-1)]
            #row=[column[0]]+[random.choice([0,1]) for x in xrange(n-1)] #origi

            matrix = xtoeplitz(column, row)
            #matrix=toeplitz(column,row) # original code

            #if  (np.linalg.matrix_rank(matrix) < n): # original code
            if  np.abs(det(matrix))<1e-4: # should be faster for small matrices
                rankzero += 1
        print n, (rankzero*1.0)/50000
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you have any idea when rank becomes quicker than det by any chance?  A very small thing, the 5000 should match the 50000 at the bottom.

Comment: det() vs rank() -- it may depend on your CPU. I just suggest to do a small test 
%timeit det(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(25,25))
vs 
%timeit matrix_rank(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(25,25))
Regarding 5000 vs 50000, I intentionally made it smaller for easier testing

Comment: det(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(25,25))) is about 42 us and matrix_rank(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(25,25))) is about 190 us. Pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines that build the lists of 0s and 1s:

```
column = [random.choice([0,1]) for x in xrange(n)]
row = [column[0]]+[random.choice([0,1]) for x in xrange(n-1)]
```

have a number of inefficiences. They build, expand, and discard lots of lists unnecessarily, and they call random.choice() on a list to get what's really just one random bit.  I sped them up by about 500% like this:

```
column = [0 for i in xrange(n)]
row = [0 for i in xrange(n)]

# NOTE: n must be less than 32 here, or remove int() and lose some speed
cbits = int(random.getrandbits(n))
rbits = int(random.getrandbits(n))

for i in xrange(n):
    column[i] = cbits & 1
    cbits >>= 1
    row[i] = rbits & 1
    rbits >>= 1

row[0] = column[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your original code is calling the lapack routine `dgesdd` to solve a linear system by first computing an LU decomposition of the input matrix.

Replacing `matrix_rank` with `det` computes the determinant using lapack's `dgetrf`, which computes only the LU decomposition of the input matrix (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html).

The asymptotic complexity of both of the `matrix_rank` and `det` calls are therefore O(n^3), the complexity of LU decomposition.

Toepelitz systems, however, can be solved in O(n^2) (according to Wikipedia). So, if you want to run your code on large matrices, it would make sense to write a python extension to call a specialized library.